# How To Export The MakeHuman 1.0.2 Skin Texture

Tags: opengl, makehuman

I'm using MakeHuman 1.0.2, and I've exported the .mhx file (for Blender). I received the .mhx file and a texture folder. The texture folder includes the following:

eyebrow - eyelashes - eye - teeth - tongue_diffuse

The skin is not included, and I can't seem to find out how to export it. I've exported the same model in several different file formats, and the texture folder never receives the skin texture.

Is there anyone that knows how to export the skin texture for MakeHuman 1.0.2?

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured this out on my own, and I'm posting this for anyone else that needs to know the answer.

MakeHuman doesn't export the default skin. You'll have to go to Materials --> Skin --> then select a skin (other than default) from the menu to the far right. After you do that, export the model, and your texture folder will have the skin texture in it.